# Returning list from async Azure API python

Tags: node.js, list, api, async-await, return

I've been using an Azure API that uses an async function to return sentiment of text.

I wanted to return this list of positive, negative, and neutral ratings so I can compare them to other similar texts...

How exactly do I read these values because what I have currently (shown below) returns the list as an undefined object.

```
async function sentimentAnalysis(client, text){
    const sentimentInput = [text];
    const sentimentResult = await client.analyzeSentiment(sentimentInput);
    var list = [];
    sentimentResult.forEach(document => {
        //console.log(`\t\tPositive: ${document.confidenceScores.positive.toFixed(2)} \tNegative: ${document.confidenceScores.negative.toFixed(2)} \tNeutral: ${document.confidenceScores.neutral.toFixed(2)}`);
        list = [document.confidenceScores.positive.toFixed(2), document.confidenceScores.negative.toFixed(2), document.confidenceScores.neutral.toFixed(2)];
        console.log(list);
        return list;
    });
}
```

```
(async () => {
        var list = await sentimentAnalysis(textAnalyticsClient, string);
})()
```

would appreciate some tips on how to return this list properly and access the elements by using list[0], list[1], etc...